# Transfer money from Wells Fargo to another WellsFargo account every month

Tags: money-transfer, transfer

I need to transfer 5k from my WellsFargo account to my landlord's WellsFargo account. But, according to the bank clerk, there is no way to do this transfer online. I have to go to the branch every month to make the deposit manually.

What are my options? I can also do it with my BOA if needed. Also, the landlord lives outside of US, so mailing them predated checks is not an option. I do have a PMA status...not sure that helps in any way.

Answer (score 1):

Ask them about Zelle.  WellsFargo says they are a member  (That's how my father and I pass money back and forth, but we're both Chase.)

https://www.wellsfargo.com/online-banking/transfers/zelle

> Zelle is the new way to move money between friends, family, coworkers, and millions of other people across the country within minutes.Footnote 11 With just an email address or mobile phone numberFootnote 22; you can easily send money to almost anyone with a U.S. bank accountFootnote 33 directly from Wells Fargo Online® and Wells Fargo Mobile®. You can also request and receive money from other people. Zelle securely connects you to more people than ever. Whether you need to pay the babysitter, cover your share of the rent, or split the cost of pizza, Zelle is the way to move money.

Note that the money goes instantly out of your account, and can't be cancelled.

Comment: Zelle typically puts daily and monthly limits on the amount you can transfer. This might be limited to $2500 daily and $4000 on a 30-day aggregation for Wells Fargo (https://www.wellsfargo.com/online-banking/transfers/zelle-terms/, 10D)

Comment: @KBRON111 hmmm.  There's always PayPal!!!

Comment: FWIW, according to the Zelle FAQ on the Wells Fargo app, "the rolling 30-day send limit is 4,000 for new recipients and 20,000 for established recipients.  Whether a recipient is new or established is based on your history of payments to the recipient."